# How to check existence of a directory in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have developed a program that is a simple file manager. For example, it lets a user create a file, delete a file, see the attribute of the files, change directory, and etc based on a CIFS path. However, I have found out a problem when I was implementing the cd command.

I have defined a global variable which will be initialized with a new path when I call FmCommandChangeDirectory. Now I wanted to check the existence of a directory/folder before I change the global working path to the new directory. I have implemented the following function but it has not able to find out a folder exists or not.

```
bool ChangePathRoot(const char* arg_computer_name)
{
    strcpy_s(g_c_RootDrive, "C:\\");
    strcpy_s(g_c_CurrentPath, "\\\\");
    strcat(g_c_CurrentPath, arg_computer_name);

    strcpy_s(g_c_ShareName, "\\C$");
    strcat(g_c_CurrentPath, g_c_ShareName);

    strcpy_s(g_c_SystemModifiablePath, "\\");
    strcat(g_c_CurrentPath, g_c_SystemModifiablePath);
    return true;
}

void ChangePathReverseBack(const char* arg_computer_name)
{
    char c_PathBuffer[_MAX_PATH];
    char c_Drive[_MAX_DRIVE];
    char c_DirectoryMain[_MAX_DIR], c_DirectoryTemp[_MAX_DIR];
    char c_Filename[_MAX_FNAME];
    char c_Extension[_MAX_EXT];

    strcpy(c_PathBuffer, g_c_CurrentPath);

    _splitpath(c_PathBuffer, c_Drive, c_DirectoryMain, c_Filename, c_Extension);
    _splitpath(c_PathBuffer, c_Drive, c_DirectoryTemp, c_Filename, c_Extension);

    char* c_MainToken = strtok(c_DirectoryMain, "\\");
    int i_StringsCounter = 0;

    while (c_MainToken != NULL)
    {
        c_MainToken = strtok(NULL, "\\");
        i_StringsCounter++;
    }

    char* c_TempToken = strtok(c_DirectoryTemp, "\\");
    int i_StringsCounterTemp = i_StringsCounter - 1;

    char c_FinalModifiedPath[MAX_PATH];
    strcpy(c_FinalModifiedPath, "\\\\");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < i_StringsCounterTemp; i++)
    {
        strcat(c_FinalModifiedPath, c_TempToken);
        strcat(c_FinalModifiedPath, "\\");
        c_TempToken = strtok(NULL, "\\");
    }

    char* c_TokenBase = NULL;
    char* c_TokenDir = NULL;
    c_TokenBase = strtok_s(c_FinalModifiedPath, "\\", &c_TokenDir);

    char* c_TokenRoot = NULL;
    char* c_TokenDirectory = NULL;
    c_TokenRoot = strtok_s(c_TokenDir, "$", &c_TokenDirectory);
    ChangePathSecondary(c_TokenRoot, arg_computer_name, c_TokenDirectory);
}

bool ChangePathRelative(const char* arg_directory)
{
    strcat(g_c_SystemModifiablePath, arg_directory);
    strcat(g_c_SystemModifiablePath, "\\");

    strcat(g_c_CurrentPath, arg_directory);
    strcat(g_c_CurrentPath, "\\");

    return true;
}

void FmCommandChangeDirectory(const char* arg_computer_name)
{
    char c_PathBuffer[_MAX_PATH];
    char c_Drive[_MAX_DRIVE];
    char c_DirectoryMain[_MAX_DIR];
    char c_Filename[_MAX_FNAME];
    char c_Extension[_MAX_EXT];

    scanf_s("%s", c_PathBuffer, MAX_PATH - 1);
    _splitpath(c_PathBuffer, c_Drive, c_DirectoryMain, c_Filename, c_Extension);

    if (!strcmp(c_PathBuffer, "\\") || !strcmp(c_PathBuffer, "/"))
    {
        ChangePathRoot(arg_computer_name);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(c_PathBuffer, ".."))
    {
        ChangePathReverseBack(arg_computer_name);
    }
    else
    {
        ChangePathRelative(c_PathBuffer);
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to implement a function that checks a path (directory) that has exist or not but I don't know how Can I Implement such function to check a directory has been existed or not.

Comment: [GetFileAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa). Consider switching to Unicode, unless you want to target Win9x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two APIs for you to use:

In addition to [GetFileAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa) mentioned by @IInspectable, you can also refer [PathFileExists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfileexistsa?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

GetFileAttributes:

> Retrieves file system attributes for a specified file or directory.

Code:

```
DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(directorypath);

if(dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES &&(dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
{
  //exist
}
else
{
  //not a vaild path
}
```

PathFileExists:

> Determines whether a path to a file system object such as a file or
>   folder is valid.

Code:

```
BOOL retval = PathFileExists(directorypath);
if(retval == 1)
{
 //file exists
}    
else
{
 //not a vaild file
}
```

Comment: Convenient as `PathFileExists` may appear, like everything else in the Shell it has a hard limit of MAX_PATH characters.